# Consuming a StreamingResponseBody with Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I've got a simple web-service that stream a file using a StreamingResponseBody.
The definition looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("/files/{filename}")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> download(@PathVariable String filename) {
    ...
    StreamingResponseBody responseBody = out -> {
        ...
    }
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentLength(byteArray.length);

    return new ResponseEntity(responseBody, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

It works well, but now, I need to consume it in a client application.
I'm using spring to consume it, but I can't find a way to read the stream and write it to a file as it flows...

I tryied using feign but it seems it doesn't support it.
I tryied using restTemplate but I can't make it work...

Does spring support streaming client side ?
Does anybody know how to do this ?
Perhaps using pure java API ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Did you find a way to do this ?

Comment: Hello no sorry. Perhaps I could have tried to override some classes. But I didn't find any solution "out of the box".

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Http Client (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12):

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
        .setScheme(scheme)
        .setHost(host)
        .setPort(port)
        .setPath(url)
        .build();
HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.get(uri).build();

try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
     CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
     InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()) {

    // Do with stream whatever you want, for example put it to File using FileOutputStream and 'inputStream' above.

}
```

Comment: Hi @PavelDudin - your answer is correct - it is a way to consume a URL.  However, the question was specifically about Spring - so you should perhaps mention that your answer is not answering the OP.

Comment: Hi @PavelDudin,
Thank you for your response.
MrR is right, I was asking specifically for spring. But your response could also be used in a spring environment.